# How to create product with default variant data using Shopify_api gem

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm getting started with the shopify api ruby gem and just about to create products atm, but I'm already stuck at something very basic ... being that I can't create a (none-variant) product if I want to send my price and inventory data along.

If I'm correct, a product without variants actually has a 'Default Title' variant with the sku, price, inventory etc. But I can't figure out the correct way to do this ... This is what I have now:

```
new_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
new_product.title = "Burton Custom Freestlye 151"
new_product.product_type = "Snowboard"
new_product.vendor = "Burton"
new_product.published = "false"
new_product.save

new_product.variants << ShopifyAPI::Variant.new(
:option1 => "Default Title",
:price => 12.95,
:inventory_management => "shopify",
:inventory_quantity => 10
)
new_product.save
```

But this results in a product without any of the default variant data.

Tried several things but I'm not getting anywhere closer (like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857132/2814321, also not working) ... And the shopify docs aren't really helpful either.

But I'm sure any of you guys can help me with this noobish problem ... right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Been able to solve it this way:

```
  variant = new_product.variants
  variant[0].price = $price
  variant[0].sku = $sku
  variant[0].weight = $g
  variant[0].weight_unit = "g"
  variant[0].inventory_quantity = $qty
  variant[0].inventory_management = "shopify"
  new_product.save
```

I guess – correct me if I'm wrong – this does work because the default variant is already existing, hence I have to access it (`variant[0]`), whereas in my question code I was trying to create a new one.